# MYSQL Error: 13 (Permission Denied)

Tags: mysql, 19.10

I am getting *Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

```
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*
```

When I run that command I get

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-20 09:32:04 CDT; 19s ago
  Process: 7287 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7295 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7295 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Server startup in progress"
    Error: 13 (Permission denied)

Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 09:32:04 sturtz.ml systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.*
```

Comment: mysql has no permission accessing its files, check user permissions in `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: who should own the files?

Comment: The same user that mysql is running on. I guess `mysql` ?!

Comment: Thank you that worked. I ran chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: Thank you to https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo for helping me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran the following and it worked on Ubuntu Server 19.10:

```bsh
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
```

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer so that it is self-standing. Just the command is not sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

You can logging to the `/var/log/mysqld` path and check the `mysql` error.

```
tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Then you can see the permission error path. Example as below.

```
"2021-01-13T04:46:06.336009Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013129] [Server] A message intended for a client cannot be sent there as no client-session is attached. Therefore, we're sending the information to the error-log instead: MY-000001 - Can't create/write to file '**/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid**' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)"
```

Now you can give access permission to above path using below command:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/
```

After that, try to start `mysqld` service .

Answer (score 0):

Similar error might also happen if you manually delete `binlog` files.

- Check `/var/log/mysql/error.log` to see the bottom lines, if the reason is related to `binlog` files.
- if **yes**, then clearing the content of file `/var/lib/mysql/binlog.index` and then restarting mysql helped me.