# Ubuntu 20.04 MySQL Datadir Permissions (Errno 13)

Tags: permissions, mysql, apparmor

askubuntu.com, I need some help debugging my MySQL setup! For the past couple years, I have been hosting my local development resources on Dropbox, and it's been working wonderfully. This past week, I decided to wipe my computer and to use Ubuntu instead of Linux Mint this time around (irrelevant, but yay!). So, on to the important details:

## Settings

The datadir entry in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` is defined as `datadir = "/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql"`.

The permissions for `/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases` **777** (sad face, but I'm trying to eliminate possibilities at this point) and the owner user/group is **mysql:mysql**, recursively.

I have defined an Apparmor alias in `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/alias` as `alias /var/lib/mysql/ -> "/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/",`. I have also added entries into `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` as

```
# Allow data dir access
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  "/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/" r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  "/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/**" rwk,
```

Furthermore, during my testing I removed MySQL from the list of enforcements using the instructions at ([How to disable AppArmor for MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144497/how-to-disable-apparmor-for-mysql)), so Apparmor should not be affecting the process at all. My output from `sudo aa-status` is

```
apparmor module is loaded.
39 profiles are loaded.
39 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/core/9289/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/9289/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /snap/snapd/7777/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/snapd/7777/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   ippusbxd
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.gimp
   snap-update-ns.snap-store
   snap-update-ns.spotify
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.gimp.gimp
   snap.gimp.hook.install
   snap.gimp.hook.post-refresh
   snap.snap-store.snap-store
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
   snap.spotify.spotify
0 profiles are in complain mode.
3 processes have profiles defined.
3 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (1066) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (980) 
   /snap/snap-store/454/usr/bin/snap-store (2422) snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

## Outputs

The command `sudo service mysql start` produces the output

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The mysqld output from the command `journalctrl -xe` is

```
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.016428Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.016478Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 6655
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.018301Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.018309Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/ is case insensitive
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.018491Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.018547Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount mysqld[6655]: 2020-06-12T23:28:26.018619Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
Jun 12 19:28:26 tehccount systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

The output of the command `sudo systemctl status mysql.service` is

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-06-12 19:28:27 EDT; 5min ago
    Process: 6671 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 6679 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 6679 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)

Jun 12 19:28:27 tehccount systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jun 12 19:28:27 tehccount systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 12 19:28:27 tehccount systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jun 12 19:28:27 tehccount systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 12 19:28:27 tehccount systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

The output of the command `sudo -u mysql /usr/sbin/mysqld` is

```
2020-06-12T23:36:08.460482Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-06-12T23:36:08.460535Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 6866
2020-06-12T23:36:08.462316Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2020-06-12T23:36:08.462334Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/ is case insensitive
2020-06-12T23:36:08.462514Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2020-06-12T23:36:08.462555Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-06-12T23:36:08.462622Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

## Other tests

Navigating to the intended mysql datadir using `cd /home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk\ Digital/Kyle/Development\ Databases/mysql/`, then using the command `sudo -u mysql touch testfile.txt` successfully creates the file */home/tehccount/Dropbox/DesignInk Digital/Kyle/Development Databases/mysql/testfile.txt*

## Summary

Despite my best efforts and an 8 hour day of work, I have been unable to figure out why the process `/usr/sbin/mysqld` cannot start. MySQL should be removed from Apparmor and the permissions of the datadir are set to a magically liberal **777** permissions. I have done this successfully before using Linux Mint with Apparmor and proper permissions. Any suggestions are welcome, and thank you.

Comment: might be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228827/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the same error, I did exactly the same things you did and got the same results.

I was moving the **/var/lib/mysql** => **/media/{user}/data/mysql**

My fix:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /media/{user}/
```

My guess is that I could mount the data directory out of the `/media/{user}/` and should work fine too

Hint: If AppArmor is blocking you, it will tell you in the output of `journalctl -xe`.

Comment: Thanks, this ended up being the problem, sorry for late reply. `~/Dropbox` installs with 700 permissions, so I just needed to add group read permissions in my case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent hours (!!!) trying to solve this exact same problem... and eventually found this here.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem when I made a migration using Prisma. After that, I ran:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql_upgrade
```

... and my problem was solved.

I got this solution from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177465/column-count-of-mysql-proc-is-wrong-expected-20-found-16-the-table-is-probabl).